# Is there a simple way to include entire applications in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

As the title implies, I am looking for a way (if any) to include entire applications in my pyinstaller executable. I have seen the `--include-binaries` option for single-file binaries, as well as some vague hints as to where to get started for what I need, but never anything specific.

Since my application uses Selenium, and I'd not like the user to install google-chrome to use my application, I'd like to include a portable version of Chrome *bundled within the exe*, as well as a copy of wireshark (https://wireshark.org).

So far, I've worked on custom cross-platform setup files for Linux and MacOS using shell scripts, but I imagine there to be a cleaner way than messy `wget` requests to url.

Thanks for the help!